# Show that $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $GF(2^n)$ for each odd $n$.

Tags: extension-field

I am trying to show that $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $GF(2^n)$ for each odd $n$.

Clearly it's true for $n=1$ since then $GF(2) = \mathbb{Z}_2$.

I think the idea is to assume $u$ is a root of $x^2+x+1$ and then calculate $[GF(p^n)(u):GF(p^n)]$. But I am having trouble doing that.

Comment: You should "odd" at the end of your question's title, otherwise it misleads...

Comment: @DonAntonio agreed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that if $x^2+x+1$ has roots in a field $F$, then they are cube roots of unity, i.e. they are elements of order $3$ in the multiplicative group $F^\times$. Also recall that $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}^\times$ is a cyclic group of size $p^n-1$.

When does the cyclic group $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}^\times$ have an element of order $3$?

Comment: $3$ should divide $p^n -1$ right?

Comment: So then $n$ must be even!

Comment: Exactly right :)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer :)